# Rewriting dynamic URLS not working (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im aware this is a question asked a lot and i have viewed them all trying so many different variations but it wont work and i dont know what im doing wrong. 
I created a .htaccess file a long time ago in order for it to point to my 404 error page which is has done fine for me but i want to rewrite the urls on my site now as there are a lot of posts and its getting messy with all the variables in the url. 
i have a page called viewpost.php which gets passed 1 variable (there are other pages aswell but this is for the example) viewpost gets passed 1 variable so it becomes /viewpost.php?ID=10

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule viewpost-ID-(.*)\.htm$ viewpost.php?ID=$1
```

i added these 2 lines to the htaccess file. i tried removing the 404 code form the file and saved it but it didnt make it work either. Is there something else i need to be doing other than adding this code to the .htaccess file?
the site is currently being hosted on atspace

```
Hosting OS  Proprietary *nix
Perl version    5.8.4
MySQL version    5.1
Perl path   /usr/bin/perl
Sendmail path   /usr/local/bin/sendmail
CGI-BIN path    not required    (You can run CGI, Perl scripts from any domain/subdomain folder)
Perl Modules    2900+ installed modules    (Click here to view the full list)
PHP Version  5.2.17 Change
PHP.INI Edit
PHP Info    [View PHP5.2.17 Info] [View PHP5.3.6 Info]
Directory Protection     Enabled
```

this is what is written on the hosting settings page. im not sure whats required for the to be able to rewrite a url but since the .htaccess file is currently working for my 404 page im assuming its set up fine?

Comment: `viewpost.php which gets passed 1 variable` ¿Where, how? Show an example of the incoming URL that holds the variable at least.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some other rules in the `.htaccess` file are overriding your rule or you could be having a case-sensitive issue. Add `[NC,QSA,L]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule viewpost-ID-(.*)\.htm /viewpost.php?ID=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

`NC` ignores the case, `QSA` appends any extra query string parameters to the destination URL and `L` tells Apache to stop processing more `RewriteRule` entries if this is matched for the current URL.

Comment: i tried that but no luck. the only other thing in the file is the 404 code and i deleted that there those 2 lines above are all i have added to the file now

Comment: @user1889580 Could it be a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: @user1889580 Okay I am out of ideas now. What about the `/` before `viewpost.php`? What does the entire request URL look like and which page should be URL rewritten (with the path)?

Comment: in the browser it would be domain.com/viewpost.php?ID=10